# Mat Input placeholder text is blurry

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material, angular-material2, angular-material-5

The matInput placeholder text is blurry on Chrome/Safari (I think everything).

Code:

```
<div class="form-group">
     <mat-form-field>
        <input matInput placeholder="Email" ngModel name="email" id="email" type="email" required>
    </mat-form-field>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
   <mat-form-field>
        <input matInput placeholder="Password" ngModel name="password" id="password" type="password" required>
   </mat-form-field>
</div>
```

Screenshot:

[image]

Comment: What version of the angular material do you use?

Comment: I am using version 5.2.4.

Comment: Each label is wrapped in an element, use the devtool to get the class name for the element that wraps the label and add `backface-visibility: hidden !important;` to its style

Comment: This probably isn't a form-field problem. In your screenshot, the other labels in white have the same problem but the white text makes it less obvious.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This issue was caused by centering the element with transform/translate 50%.

Using flex box and aligning the item center fixed the issue!

Just a heads up!